# mount --bind /dev sometimes "kills" tty until unmounted

Tags: tty, udev, umount

I have a script that uses `sudo mount --bind /dev other/dev` and then later uses `sudo umount other/dev` to unmount. After some random number of runs, we can somehow enter an odd state where the main tty stops existing, and the whole desktop environment starts malfunctioning (new applications won't start, or they crash, and firefox can't redraw pages and they freeze, etc...) and `tty` in my terminal says `not a tty`, and the terminal fails to open new instances. I'm not using ssh or any other remote functions, so the loss of the tty for my local terminal is absurd.

The only way to fix it is to reboot or to enter a different tty with `CTRL+ALT+F1` or similar, log in, and force `other/dev` to unmount (normal asking says it is busy). After this the tty is magically revived and everything works again. I'm only actually mounting `dev` to get another `/dev/null`, so an easier workaround probably exists for me, but this is still very strange!

Is there some explanation for this odd behavior?
I'm on 18.04.2 LTS.

Comment: You can make a character device like `/dev/null` using `mknod` as decribed here: [How to create /dev/null?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/how-to-create-dev-null). This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: @steeldriver, That is what I've done. I mainly wanted to post this because it was so bizarre that I wanted it out on the internet somewhere in case anyone experiences something similar. It is possibly harder to side step in other scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

If the propagation type of `/dev` is shared, then mount and unmount operations will be copied from `/dev/` to `other/dev` and vice-versa, unmounting `other/dev` will therefore unmount from `/dev` everything that was mounted after the bind mount.

To solve this set the propagation type of `other/dev` before unmounting it:

```
mount --make-rprivate other/dev
```